# Alternative method for Android push notification

Tags: java, android

Is there an alternative to using Google C2DM for push notifications with Android? I ask because the app I'm working on will only run when the device is connected to a specific network. It's an app for members of this specific company and notifications will only come from that companies server. Since everything is "in-house" does it even make sense to push them to google just to have them come back to the same network? I've heard something about JMS. Does anyone know if that will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are definitely some options. I played with UrbanAirship a bit and it seems nice. Check it out http://urbanairship.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Tokudu](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/) . It uses  IBM’s MQTT broker to handle the server work. Try it out.